# ExpiresByType text/x-javascript and google analytics

Tags: javascript, caching, google-analytics, expires-header

Before implementing Google Analytics on my site with the latest javaScript code directly after the body tag, I had and still have this code in my .htaccess:

```
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
```

Does this mean that every user that had visited the site before I implemented the analytics code will skip it due to javascript being cached?

Comment: Bit of an aside, but... are you really serving your JavaScript files with a `text/x-javascript` content type?

Answer (score 1):

### **Short answer**

As long as you serve it in the header or in a new external .js file, they won't skip it.

### **Long answer**

Patrick Sexton from feedthebot.com explains it perfectly [here:](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html)

> **Common caching issue**
>
> If you list your html and images to be cached for one year or some
> other long time period, remember that this can mean if you make a
> change to your pages they may not be seen by all users. This is
> because the users will look to cached files rather than the live ones.
> If you have file that you tweak occasionally (example - a CSS file)
> you can overcome the cache issue by using URL fingerprinting.
>
> **URL fingerprinting**
>
> Getting a fresh (not cached) file resource is possible by having a
> unique name. An example would be if our css file was named "main.css"
> we could name it "main_1.css" instead. The next time we change it we
> can call it "main_2.css". This is useful for files that change
> occasionally.

Comment: Your "Short answer" answers the OP's question. However, whilst the "Long answer" goes into more detail about _caching_, it does not explain it any better - with respect to the OP's specific question.